# How dynamically change environment variable in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to change environment variable when I am inserting custom URL in text box and that will be change in Environment Variable on the basis of that am showing response on website.

Here is my TypeScript code:

```js
   generateQRCode() {
      this.value = this.qrcodename;
      localStorage.clear()
      localStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(this.qrcodename));

  }
```

HTML

```html
  <div class="form-group">
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="qr"
        aria-describedby="qr"
        placeholder="Enter code"
        required
        [(ngModel)]="qrcodename"
      />
    </div>
```

and i want to change at this baseUrl with value of qrcodename

```
export const environment = {
  production: false
   baseUrl: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"

};
```

Answer (score 1):

I just do with local storage and access it on where i want to use this Url input here is my simple code

```
  getDashboardData(): Observable<any> {

    let url = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
    return this.http.get(url + "/dashboard");
```

}